# Calling function form external js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have external js and it is called inside one of the div's in my HTML.
In that external file I have following code:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = '$("body").prepend(\'<input type="hidden" id="sid" value="0">\');var vl=0;$(".sbut").click(function(){vl ++; var snew=vl;$("#sid").val(snew).trigger("change");});';         
document.head.appendChild(script);

$("#sid").change(function(){
   alert("change");
});
```

Alert is not triggered. If I try this:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = '$("body").prepend(\'<input type="hidden" id="sid" value="0">\');var vl=0;$(".sbut").click(function(){vl ++; var snew=vl;$("#sid").val(snew).trigger("change");});$("#sid").change(function(){somef();alert("change");});    ';      
document.head.appendChild(script);

function somef(){
   alert("change");
}
```

Than I get that my function somef is not defined. I am guessing this had to do something with order of my functions, but i am not sure what exactly. Can somebody suggest me what is proper way to do this? Also, my external script (fscript.js) is called inside one of the div's in HTML and I cannot change that as i do not have access to HTML. That is why i append input and script also.

Comment: Where in the page is/are the `.sbut` element(s)? Any `.sbut` elements that are lower in the page than the script won't have a click handler attached to them. Also... if you are able to use ES2015 (or transpile from it) writing that HTML that you are injecting would be a lot more readable using template strings since you can use newlines in them.

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't understand why you are writing this code as a string and injecting a script tag. You are already loading an external script, there should be no reason it can't just be written in that file. Unless you are also injecting jQuery in part of this script that you did not show us and then this other script tag to ensure order of execution?

Comment: Although, you use jQuery outside the script string too so I'm assuming it is already loaded in the page?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `sid` element dynamically and hence it is not available when bind change event handler, try below code to bind event handler

```
$(document).on("change","#sid",function(){
   alert("change");
});
```

Comment: Input's value is changing correctly, i don't have any errors in console, but change is not cached in external file

Comment: You need to click outside the input box once changes done. can you clear you browser cache and try. One more thing is like `sid` must be unique through out the DOM.

Comment: It is unique, only value is changed and it is changing properly. But it seems that issue is external script and caching change. I tried deleting browsers cache also, and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, I don't see a reason to write your script as a string and inject it as a script tag. `fscript.js` is already being loaded so you can just write your code in it, it will run in the same context as if it were in a script tag in the page.

This is the way I would write it.

```js
// Use an IIFE to encapsulate our code so our variables don't leak into
// the global namespace. This will ensure they don't collide with
// and existing JS in the page avoiding creating bugs in both our code
// and the surrounding page
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var vl = 0,
    // create the sid element and store a reference to the
    // returned jQuery object in a variable we can use to
    // refer to it later
    sid = $('<input type="hidden" id="sid" value="0">');

  // attach the change event to sid
  sid.change(function() {
     alert('Change, sid is now ' + sid.val());
  });     

  // inject sid into the DOM
  $('body').prepend(sid);

  // use event delegation to add the click event for .sbut
  // this will ensure that any .sbut elements in the HTML
  // after this script is run will have the click handler
  // If you know that .sbut will always appear above the place
  // where your script runs, you could just use a normal
  // jQuery selector instead.
  $(document).on('click', '.sbut', function() {
      vl++;
      // there doesn't seem to be any need to create the
      // snew var here, its value is exactly the same as vl
      // at this point, just use vl
      sid.val(vl).trigger('change');
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="sbut">.sbut</button>
```

I use an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)
to wrap the code to encapsulate it so that it doesn't interfere with other code on the page
and visa versa. It's also a good practice to use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode),
it can help avoid some common types of bugs and enforce some best practices.

I used [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach the click event to `.sbut` because I don't know if any `.sbut` elements occur after your script is loaded, it seems that might be the case. If you know that `.sbut` will always occur before your script is loaded, you could just change it to a normal `$('.sbut').click(function() {});` handler.